# Shiny reactivity fundamentals - reactive wrapper(s) needed? if so, which and where?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm looking for help on fundamentals of Shiny reactivity. In the past, I've had small enough datasets that I could read in `.csv`s, tidy into a `data.frame`, then just passively filter it in the server block with the inputs. Now I have bigger `.csv`s and many with lots of frequency data  that for performance sake, I'd prefer to bind/uncount just the data the user selects (instead of waiting for filtering and plotting). I'm not sure what kind of reactive wrappers or filters might be best for this case. Any help tremendously appreciated.

reproducible `app.r`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# generate sample p & t observation data
zone <- c(rep("a", 6), rep("b", 6), rep("c", 6), rep("d", 6))
set.seed(1)
val <- rnorm(24, 12, 18)
param <- rep(c("p", "t"), 12)
p_t <- data.frame(zone, val, param)
p_rawcsv <- p_t %>% filter(param == "p")
t_rawcsv <- p_t %>% filter(param == "t")

# generate sample elevation frequency data - too many obs to uncount all at once
set.seed(2)
val <- sample(50, 24)
count <- sample(200000, 24)
e_countcsv <- data.frame(zone, val, count) %>% 
              mutate(param = "elev")

ui <- 
shinyUI(fluidPage(

sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(

    selectizeInput(
      "zone", "zone", choices = unique(p_rawcsv$zone), 
      selected = c("a"), 
      multiple = TRUE),

  checkboxGroupInput("param", "parameter",                
          choices = c("elev", "p", "t"), selected = "elev")
        ),

mainPanel(

  tabsetPanel(position=c("right"),
              tabPanel(strong("plot"), 
              plotOutput("reg_plot",  height = "750px")) )))
         ) 
)

server <- function(input, output) {

output$reg_plot <- renderPlot({

  zones  <- zone %in% input$zone #after I posted, realizing `zone` undefined..
  params <- param %in% input$param #same for `param`, and thinking this data block should pbly be above the renderPlot, somehow in a wrapper

  t <-   t_rawcsv %>% filter(zone %in% zones, param %in% params) 
   #head(t)
   #   zone        val param
   #1     a  15.305580     t
   #2     a  40.715054     t
   #3     a  -2.768431     t
  p <-   p_rawcsv %>% filter(zone %in% zones, param %in% params) 
   #   zone        val param
   #1     a  0.7238314     p
   #2     a -3.0413150     p
   #3     a 17.9311399     p

  elev <-   e_countcsv %>% 
            filter(zone %in% zones, param %in% params)  %>% 
            uncount(count) #now uncount, just for the selected
    #head(elev)
    #    zone       val param
    #1      a 0.7238314  elev
    #1.1    a 0.7238314  elev
    #1.2    a 0.7238314  elev

 df <-   rbind(elev, t, p)

 p <- ggplot(df, aes(val), color = zone, linetype = param) +   
      labs(y = "proportion of total", x = NULL) +
      stat_ecdf(pad = FALSE)  + coord_flip()

 print(p)

 }) 

 }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure, what kind of wrappers you are looking for, but I tried to streamline your code, staying in the tidyverse. If you have lots of data changing to data.table might be worth the effort, since it will speed things up.

I usually use print statements within render functions to print objects to the console where I am not sure how they look like or just to check whether they are working properly. Running you app will also get the reactive data frame `data()` printed so you can check if it matches your expected output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

# generate sample p & t observation data
zone <- c(rep("a", 6), rep("b", 6), rep("c", 6), rep("d", 6))
set.seed(1)
val <- rnorm(24, 12, 18)
param <- rep(c("p", "t"), 12)
p_t <- data.frame(zone, val, param, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
p_rawcsv <- p_t %>% filter(param == "p")
t_rawcsv <- p_t %>% filter(param == "t")

# generate sample elevation frequency data - too many obs to uncount all at once
set.seed(2)
val <- sample(50, 24)
count <- sample(200000, 24)
e_countcsv <- data.frame(zone, val, count,  stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(param = "elev")

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(

      selectizeInput(
        "zone", "zone", choices = unique(p_rawcsv$zone),
        selected = c("a"),
        multiple = TRUE),

      checkboxGroupInput("param", "parameter",
                         choices = c("elev", "p", "t"), selected = "elev")
    ),

    mainPanel(

      tabsetPanel(position=c("right"),
                  tabPanel(strong("plot"),
                           plotOutput("reg_plot",  height = "750px")) )))

  ),

server = function(input, output) {

  # this might be the reactive your question was about?
  data <- reactive({

    p_t %>%
      filter(param %in% input$param,
             zone %in% input$zone) %>%
    bind_rows({e_countcsv %>%
      filter(param %in% input$param,
             zone %in% input$zone) %>%
      uncount(count)})

  })


  output$reg_plot <- renderPlot({

    # use these for debugging
    print(input$param)
    print(input$zone)
    print(data())

    ggplot(data(), aes(val), color = zone, linetype = param) +
      labs(y = "proportion of total", x = NULL) +
      stat_ecdf(pad = FALSE)  + coord_flip()
  })

}

)
```

**Update:** 
If you want to do the data wrangling part with data.table you can use the following code. You can see the app runs somewhat smoother.

```
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

# generate sample p & t observation data
zone <- c(rep("a", 6), rep("b", 6), rep("c", 6), rep("d", 6))
set.seed(1)
val <- rnorm(24, 12, 18)
param <- rep(c("p", "t"), 12)
p_t <- data.table(zone, val, param, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# generate sample elevation frequency data - too many obs to uncount all at once
set.seed(2)
val <- sample(50, 24)
count <- sample(200000, 24)
e_countcsv <- data.table(zone, val, count,  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
e_countcsv <- e_countcsv[, param := "elev"]


    shinyApp(

      ui = fluidPage(

        sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(

          selectizeInput(
            "zone", "zone", choices = unique(p_t[param == "p"]$zone),
            selected = c("a"),
            multiple = TRUE),

          checkboxGroupInput("param", "parameter",
                             choices = c("elev", "p", "t"), selected = "elev")
        ),

        mainPanel(

          tabsetPanel(position=c("right"),
                      tabPanel(strong("plot"),
                               plotOutput("reg_plot",  height = "750px")) )))

      ),

    server = function(input, output) {

      data <- reactive({

        p <- p_t[param %in% input$param & zone %in% input$zone]

        if ( "elev" %in% input$param) {
          e <- e_countcsv[param %in% c("elev") & zone %in% input$zone][
            rep(seq(.N), count), !"count"]
          rbindlist(list(p,e))
        } else {p}

      })


      output$reg_plot <- renderPlot({

        # use these for debugging
        print(input$param)
        print(input$zone)
        print(data())

        ggplot(data(), aes(val), color = zone, linetype = param) +
          labs(y = "proportion of total", x = NULL) +
          stat_ecdf(pad = FALSE)  + coord_flip()
      })

    }

    )
```

Comment: Perfect! And I was really missing handy debug output. Would it be straightforward to add what would need to change for a more data.table centric approach for the filtering/binding?

Comment: I provide another app relying on data.table. It runs definitely smoother.